# Webpack Module Federation React dynamic import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

hello, I hope you will help me and save my day!
I'm trying to expose components and load them dynamically in the host app.
When I load dumb components like div with text all is fine but when I try to load a component with hooks then an error occurs:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I've chosen the dynamic import solution because I want to keep a stable host app in the case when the remote app is down.
I read somewhere if I use dynamic import then I can get rid of the shared components in the Module Federation Configuration of both apps.

Underneath Module Federation Plugin configurations from both apps to show the bigger picture:

Host app:

```
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'container',
      }),
```

Remote app:

```
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'documentStore',
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        exposes: {
          './Documents': './src/pages/Documents/Documents',
        },
      }),
```

I've also tried shared dependencies for the `react`, `react-dom`, with `eager` option as `true` or `false`, and all approaches failed as well.

Thank you in advance and have a good day folks!

Answer (score 0):

If i got module federation right, there is no downside when using shared dependencies. (But im not an expert)

There is also an example at the [module-federation repo](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples) with [self-healing](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/self-healing) (i know, sounds like a dream)
If application b depends on a dep from application a but application a do not provide this dep application b automatically pulls his own vendor.

Seems to me that you have multiple react instances

Maybe you could try singleton option of a shared dependency:

```
  shared: {
    // adds react as shared module
    react: {
      requiredVersion: deps.react, // deps here is package.json
      singleton: true,
    },
  },
```